# Empty Cells which has vlookup formula

Tags: excel, vba

The formula on Column C is

```
=VLOOKUP($B2,Sheet1!$A$2:$C$100,2,0)
```

which gets the value from `Sheet1` and it works okay.

Now I want to put a condition

```
If cell D2:D100 is empty then make C2:C100 empty
```

`C2:C100` contains a vlookup formula, and I'd like to clean the formula from the cell.

Secondly, how do we run this in a macro `=VLOOKUP($B2,Sheet1!$A$2:$C$100,2,0)`?

Comment: So, to clarify, you want to check the range `D2:100` and if it's empty you want to **completely** remove the formula in range `C2:C100`?  And you want a macro to restore the vlookup formula?

Comment: Yes you are right sir.

Comment: Are you sure you want a macro to do that?
I mean you can get the same result if you change your formula to something like:

    `=IF(ISBLANK($D2), "", VLOOKUP($B2,Sheet1!$A$2:$C$100,2,0))`

Comment: @manimatters That's a good idea, you should post your answer!

Answer (score 0):

manimatters has a good solution to use a ISBLANK with an IF formula.  If you still want a macro for your second question, I've provided it below.

This macro will set the formula in *C2* to `=VLOOKUP($B2,Sheet1!$A$2:$C$101,2,FALSE)` and then fill this formula down to *C100*.

```
Sub RestoreVLookup()
    Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(R[0]C2,Sheet1!R1C1:R101C3,2,FALSE)"
    Range("C2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C100"), Type:=xlFillDefault        
End Sub
```

Let's look at the different parts:

`Range("C2").FormulaR1C1` - Assign a formula to cell `C2`.
`"=VLOOKUP(R[0]C2,Sheet1!R1C1:R101C3,2,FALSE)"` This is the formula assigned

`R[0]` - Relative row with an offset of zero.  `R[1]` would point to the row above and `R[-1]` would refer to the row below.

`C2` - The 2nd column (aka column B)

`Range("C2").Select` - Select cell `C2`

`Selection.AutoFill ... Type:=xlFillDefault` - autofill the formula from `C2` to `C100`.